# (Python MySQL) How do I use the LIKE wildcard with a variable?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I want to do a search for names similar to the variable
I want to do something like this:

```
c.execute("SELECT Book_name FROM Books WHERE Book_name LIKE %'hello'%;")
```

But with the use of a variable instead of the string. Something like this:

```
c.execute("SELECT Book_name FROM Books WHERE Book_name LIKE %%s% ;"%(value,))
```

Comment: Try `c.execute("SELECT Book_name FROM Books WHERE Book_name LIKE '\%%s\%' ;"%(value,))` - i.e. quote `%` literals and wrap the pattern into quotes. Or use a function: `c.execute("SELECT Book_name FROM Books WHERE Book_name LIKE CONCAT('%', %s, '%') ;"%(value,))`

Answer (score 0):

I would pass my variable like so in the execution of the cursor with my query defined as a variable. You can pass multiple variables with simply passing other ? and separating your variables with a comma in the same order as the ?.

Here is an example of how I would do it.

```
var = 'whynot'
query = """SELECT Book_name 
           FROM Books 
           WHERE Book_name LIKE ?"""
c.execute(query, ("%" + var + "%"))
```